# gcc linking error in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, linker

I'm trying to compile a c file that opens a common dialog box in netbeans using cygwin. The relevant code is:

```c
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn); // SEE NOTE BELOW
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";

if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
    // Do something usefull with the filename stored in szFileName 
}
```

When compiling, I get:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__GetOpenFileNameA@4'
```

As I understand it, the comdlg library is not linked properly, but I cant get it right. Does anyone know how to add the library to the linker?